# Foreground app notification is almost empty, background app gets notification but without custom data

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, foregroundnotification

I'm working on an **Android** app in **Kotlin** and I want to send notification in order to click on it and open a custom view.

I've implemented notification thanks to **Firebase**. I can send notification thans to Firebase, but the notification are well displayed (with the right icone (= triangle), the right title and the right message) only if the app is in **background**, but the custom data (key => val) provided in firebase are not detected.

For the **foreground** app, if I send the notification from Firebase, I can display the custom data (key => val), but the notification doesn't have title, message or custom icone (it has the square/rounded icone)

Instead of showing all my code, I prefere to give you the link I've followed.

https://www.android4dev.com/firebase-pushnotification-android/

I want to have the same result on both side so I can get the custom data.

See the result :

[image]

Comment: Anyone's got the answer ? Same problem for me.

Comment: Anyone got the answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of `FCM` messages and the behaviour changes based on it.

- `Notification messages` (these are handled by the SDK automatically)
- `Data messages` (handled by the app)

> Use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a
>   notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you
>   want to process the messages on your client app.
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

I think that you should use `data messages` instead of `notification messages` to have a consistent behaviour.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you have any sample links to give please ? (not only docs, can't find a recent example...)